# How to link 2 member Ids to 1 band?

Tags: mysql

I just began learning MySql, and there is one problem that I can't solve.
I have two tables, that looks like this.
The point is, that I would like to connect MemberID from *Member* to MemberID from *Band*, but as you can see, there are few people in the same band. I'm unsure how am I suppose to do it, so that I can connect  few members to one band in 1 column.
[Member](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ichav.png)
[Band](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMxar.png)

Comment: If one member may participate in one band only then add reference column to members table, else create separate relational table which stores IDs pairs member-band.

Answer (score 1):

Check the relations. You can do it with a foreign key on your members, that references band id, if the members only can have one band. If the members can have more than one band, you need to do a manytomany table, that have member id and band id.